# number of self-conjugate partitions of n (with all parts even)

Tags: combinatorics

What is the generating function?

I know the g.f. of number of self-conjugate partitions and the g.f. of the number of partitions with all parts even. But I don't know how to proceed after that.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: What do you get for the first few values of $n$? You can search for the sequence in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/).

Comment: I think an explicit expression is not necessary. Only the generating function is needed.

Comment: I repeat. What do you get for the first few values of $n$? Did you do any work on this question at all?

Comment: OK, I got 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1...

Comment: This is a start. Can you explain all the zeros? They seen to come in threes.

Comment: I think I figure it out by using the Ferrer diagram. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the solution with the help of Somos.

Just a hint for others:
Take use of the Ferrers diagram, and replace each point in the diagram with something else. (e.g. a set of points maybe?)